# C Library call to the user code ( function pointers vs external symbols)

Tags: c, function, pointers, callback

I'm implementing a library that needs to call to the user code for different reasons.

The question:
For example let assume that we call the user code to encrypt something (we let the user do this for two reasons: maybe he will exploit a hardware implementation of the algorithm or maybe he do not want to implement the cryptography and just return the string as it is at the moment of the call).

It is more elegant to let the user pass me a function pointer to the "ciphering" functions e.g

```
void (* encrypt_f)(void *ctx, void *dst, void *src, size_t n);
void (* decrypt_f)(void *ctx, void *dst, void *src, size_t n);
void (* set_key_f)(void *ctx, void *key, size_t n);

struct cipher_interface
{
    encrypt_f encrypt;
    decrypt_f decrypt;
    set_key_f  set_key;`
};
```

And i will call the user code from the library by using something like:

```
struct lib_ctx
{
    void *usr_ctx;
    struct cipher_interface *usr_itf;
    /* ... */
};

void lib_function(struct lib_ctx *ctx, ...)
{
    /* ... */
    if (ctx->usr_itf->encrypt != NULL)
        ctx->usr_itf->encrypt(ctx->usr_ctx, ...); 
}
```

With the above solution the user, if he do not whant to implement a certain functionality he can store a null pointer in the function pointer.

Another solution is to simply left some unresolved symbols for the functions the user must implement:

```
void usr_encrypt(void *ctx, void *dst, void *src, size_t n);
void usr_decrypt(void *ctx, void *dst, void *src, size_t n);
void usr_set_key(void *ctx, void *key, size_t n);

struct lib_ctx
{
    void *usr_ctx;
    /* ... */
};

void lib_function(struct lib_ctx *ctx, ...)
{
    /* ... */
    usr_encrypt(ctx->usr_ctx, ...); 
}
```

In this second solution, if the user do not want to use a certain functionality it must at least define an empty function to resolve the symbol.

```
void usr_encrypt(...) {}
```

My library is a network protocols library and have a lot of calls to user code like the ones presented here (e.g. hdlc_connection_indication to notify the user about the hdlc connection success, etc)

What it is the best approach for this kind of situations?

Comment: Yes, probably use function pointers. Give each of them a client data. Register the client functions with their client data.

Answer (score 1):

I think the former approach, with explicit function pointers handled "as data" by the code, is the best.

The latter appraoch makes it very hard to have *two* (or more) users of the same library, perhaps for different contexts, inside a single program and thus is very annoying to deal with.

Consider for example encrypting network and disk traffic, those might be in two totally different sub-systems inside an application, yet they might still want to use the same library's services. With an explicit "context" passed to/from the library that's painless to do; with link-level symbol magic it's almost impossible.

Answer (score 0):

The first solution is certainly more flexible but the second one is a bit more efficient because all the calls are direct and also because it does not contain all the null pointers checks before the calls. 
I'm uncertain about the path that i will take yet :/